# Export to .CSV in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I have an app that takes information from an indeed.com search result. The code returns each url from the search result and makes an array of all the information in each url. At least I think it does. The result is supposed to be a .CSV file with the result from the query. here is the code.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const articles = []
const articlesB = []
const url1 = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=biotechnology&l=Frederick%2C%20MD&from=searchOnHP&vjk=35cd4f4f40383593'

const fastCsv = require("fast-csv");
const fs = require("fs");
const ws = fs.createWriteStream("data.csv");




getUrl()
function getUrl() {
        axios(url1)
            .then(response => {
                const html = response.data
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)

                $('.jcs-JobTitle', 'li', html).each(function () {
                    let Title = $(this).attr('href')
                    Title = 'https://www.indeed.com'+Title
                    articles.push({
                        Title,
                    })
                })
                getJobs(articles)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

function getJobs(urls){
    let num = 1
    urls.forEach(element => {
        axios(element.Title)
            .then(response => {
                const html = response.data
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)



                $('h1', html).each(function () {
                    const Text = $(this).text()
                    articlesB.push({
                        Text,
                    })
                })
                $('h2', html).each(function () {
                    const Text = $(this).text()
                    articlesB.push({
                        Text
                    })
                })
                $('p', html).each(function () {
                    const Text = $(this).text()
                    articlesB.push({
                        Text
                    })
                })
                let jsonData = []
                console.log(num++ +'-'.repeat(99)) // Separator
                articlesB.forEach(items=>{
                    jsonData = ((items.Text))
                    console.log(jsonData)
                })
                console.log('-'.repeat(100)) // Separator
                writeToCsv(JSON.stringify(jsonData))

            }).catch(err => console.log(err))

    })

}

function writeToCsv(jsonData){
    fastCsv
        .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
        .on("finish", function() {
            console.log("Write to CSV successfully!");
        })
        .pipe(ws);
}

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("server running on PORT " + PORT))
```

however it returns this error:
TypeError: rows.reduce is not a function

I believe the problem is that I am not making a proper array. Please enlighten me on what I am doing wrong.

Edit, this is what the code is currently like.

```
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const articles = []
const articlesB = []
const url1 = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=biotechnology&l=Frederick%2C%20MD&from=searchOnHP&vjk=35cd4f4f40383593'

const fastCsv = require("fast-csv");
const fs = require("fs");
const ws = fs.createWriteStream("data.csv");




getUrl()
function getUrl() {
        axios(url1)
            .then(response => {
                const html = response.data
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)

                $('.jcs-JobTitle', 'li', html).each(function () {
                    let Title = $(this).attr('href')
                    Title = 'https://www.indeed.com'+Title
                    articles.push({
                        Title,
                    })
                })
                getJobs(articles)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

function getJobs(urls){
    let num = 1
    urls.forEach(element => {
        axios(element.Title)
            .then(response => {
                const html = response.data
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)



                $('h1', html).each(function () {
                    const Text = $(this).text()
                    articlesB.push({
                        Text,
                    })
                })
                $('h2', html).each(function () {
                    const Text = $(this).text()
                    articlesB.push({
                        Text
                    })
                })
                $('p', html).each(function () {
                    const Text = $(this).text()
                    articlesB.push({
                        Text
                    })
                })
                let jsonData = []
                console.log(num++ +'-'.repeat(99)) // Separator
                const data = articlesB.map(el => el.Text);
                /*articlesB.forEach(items=>{
                    jsonData = ((items.Text))
                    console.log(jsonData)
                })*/
                console.log('-'.repeat(100)) // Separator
                writeToCsv(data)

            }).catch(err => console.log(err))

    })

}

function writeToCsv(jsonData){
    fastCsv
        .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
        .on("finish", function() {
            console.log("Write to CSV successfully!");
        })
        .pipe(ws);
}

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("server running on PORT " + PORT))
```

Comment: `jsonData` is a string. Why are you passing JSON to `write`? The [example in the docs](https://c2fo.github.io/fast-csv/docs/formatting/methods) shows an array.

Comment: @Quentin so it is a string? basically, I want the data from Indeed.com to be written to a .CSV

Comment: Yes? The output of `JSON.stringify` is a string. The clue is in the name.

Comment: Okay can .push everything into an array?

Comment: Replace `articlesB.forEach(...)` with `const data = articlesB.map(el => el.Text);`, remove `jsonData` and call `writeToCsv(data)` instead of `writeToCsv(JSON.stringify(jsonData))`. There is no JSON in your code.

Comment: @jabaa that did write a .csv file. However, the output is 0,1,2,3,4,5..., 26 not the actual data pulled from indeed.com

Comment: Could you fix the code in the question to contain your current state?

Comment: @jabaa like that? sorry for being a newb but, I am just trying to understand the concepts here.